# What is the purpose of "issues" and "volumes" in journal publications in relation to DOIs and citations?

Tags: citations, terminology, doi

I think I have stumbled once again over the meanings of "issue" and "volume".

So I have found [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12541-010-0035-y) which declares both fields. Now I used JabRef's `DOI to BibTeX` to pull the info and it worked as expected. But it only pulled the volume number.

But sometimes I noticed the DOI database only pulls the issue number for an article, more than only giving the volume number. Why?

I suppose one should prefer using the issue because there are (usually) issues of a journal ("magazine") in a year... right?

Comment: If JabRef pull's an issue number, but not the volume, that's a bug (either in JabRef or the publishers database).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess your question is about citing an article. If the article you want to cite  is in a journal which have both volume and issue number (this is very often the case). Then you should write both of them.

The issue is the booklet number in which the article was published. They are grouped together to make a volume. Often one volume correspond to all the issues of one given year, but not always. Page numbers usually run sequentially through a volume (issue 2's first page will be numbered one higher than the last page of issue 1 and so on).

Finding the article in a (paper) library is easier if you have both the volume and issue number since you directly know which booklet you need to consult. While helpful, the issue number isn't strictly required in order to find a particular article. Indeed, libraries often bind all the issues of a single volume into a hard-backed book where the page number is sufficient.

Today with electronic paper those notions might have lost their meaning,  and in the end, the DOI is probably the best way to share a reference.  However,  it is still in the habit to provide both issue and volume number, and given what they mean, it does not really make sense to have only one of them. The last word will go to the editor of the journal you are publishing the reference in and the bibliography style may or may not include the issue number. So for your personal bibliography, it seems safer to have it for the day you publish in a journal which request issue numbers.

For this particular paper in jabref, I don't know why only one get pulled. Maybe it is a bug, or a database error.

Comment: The pages are typically numbered sequentially within a volume: issue 1 might be pages 1-150, issue 2 pages 151-300 and so on. As such, the issue number is typically redundant so, while it's best to cite both volume and issue number, a reference will usually still make sense with only one of them, as long as that one is the volume.

Comment: @DavidRicherby is correct. In my field it's usual to refrain from citing issue numbers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, but again if you go to a library you probably don't want to pull each issue to find the one with the right page.

Comment: @Moriarty you mean the journal will not put it in the bibliography or you would not give it when providing 'informally' a reference to someone?

Comment: @Lynda: Previously, it was common for libraries to bind all issues of a single volume into a hard-covered book. Then you would just use the volume number to find the right volume, and the page number to find the right article. The issue number would be of little use — it would be actually a bit difficult to find the right issue in the volume. It seems that more recently libraries have got a bit lazy and just keep individual issues as is, which means that knowing the issue number is actually useful.

Comment: @Lynda I agree that that makes the issue number helpful and I include it in my own citations. But, if the issue number is missing, it's hardly the end of the world: you can fairly accurately guestimate the issue number by eye based on the page number you're looking for and the thickness of the individual issues. The issue number isn't *required*, which is what your answer states.

Comment: @Lynda The issue number is absent from the journal's bibliography, for example: Smith J., 2009, MNRAS, 407, 3125. Most people read the electronic journals now, so issue numbers are becoming increasingly irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Definitely not the end of the world, the information is provided for convenience and is indeed redundant. And nowadays with DOI and electronic copies, almost everything seems kind of redundant.

Comment: @Moriarty I corrected my answer to precise it is the journal choice to have or not the issue number.

Comment: So if a paper is published in *08/2004*, you say this would be `volume 8 in 2004`?

Comment: @henry No, you cannot exchange the date/issue/vol. Each journal has its own numbering so the issue for august is not necessary 8. Thus you cannot deduct the issue/volume number from the date (I am assuming when writing 08/2004, you meant August 2004)

Comment: I don't know if it is a date. The source I am relating this example to, was actually published in August of 2004, however the numbering was simply provided as *08/2004*.

Comment: Ok you are right, each journal does is its own way. This journal with the *08/2004* declares it has several "Ausgaben" per year, which translates to "issues".

Comment: @henry It can happen that a journal publishes more than one volume per year. There are journals with 20000 pages yearly, you don't want all of that in one volume. There is more info in my answer to [When citing a journal paper, should I use the online publication year or the print publication year?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/when-citing-a-journal-paper-should-i-use-the-online-publication-year-or-the-pri/16615#16615)

Answer (score 2):

The issue number is useful when pulling a hard copy of the journal before it has been bound.  Some libraries wait a year or two before binding.  So during that time you have loose issues.

P.s.  Some people still use the library, still read hard copies.  Not everyone is young and computer oriented--you'll get the wrong perspective if you think the SE demographic represents Academia. Don't assume everyone is using the screen only.

Comment: I learned to lookup articles using physical volumes and issues. The day I found I could read some computer science articles sitting at my desk using Mosaic was an absolute delight. Don't ignore the old and computer orientated. We do exist.